# Memory leak if load from NSCachesDirectory

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I load a lot of annotations from plist, all loads fine, but if I load from NSCachesDirectory memory leak tool show me an leak. If I load from url, no leaks. I use ARC in project.

memory leak

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path]; // leaking here
```

no leaking

```
NSString *urlStr = [[NSString alloc] 
                    initWithFormat:@"http://www.domain.com/test.plist" ];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: Actually, I see now you've already asked this question, and that one actually has more data. Please don't just re-ask a question, especially with far less context/information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory leak on new thread using arc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653016/memory-leak-on-new-thread-using-arc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why instruments would show a leak with one and not the other, but it's almost certainly due to some issue that's not represented by these code snippets. You can verify that by simply using the URL method (which is the suggested way to go anyway, prefer using file URLs over paths with new code) to locate the file:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSURL* fileURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:&error] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];
if( !fileURL ) { /* deal with error */ }
// If this still leaks, it's due to the way your code is structured and
// you will have to provide more details.
NSDictionary* dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
```

Comment: @PavelKaljunen That means it's something else in your code and you need to post a lot more context. It's far more difficult to generate an actual leak in ARC than in managed memory code. The only way to really do it is with an orphaned strong cycle. You need to edit your question with more information/details.